# add comment to zip file in r

Tags: r, zip

I'm trying to add comments to zip files using the function zip in R. For instance, I need to add the comment "S:spList". So, I assumed a proper way to do it may be:

```
data(iris)
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")
zip(zipfile="iris.zip", files="iris.csv", extras="-z S:spList")
file.remove("iris.csv")
```

I get in the console following output:

```
adding: iris.csv (deflated 77%)
enter new zip file comment (end with .):
zip warning: name not matched: S:spList
```

Apparently the function zip makes and attempt to add a comment, but the comment itself is giving it troubles.

Can somebody help me?
Many thanks in advance for any advice

Migue

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: This may work as an alternative - `cmd <- sprintf("%s %s <<< %s", Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip"), "-qz iris.zip iris.csv", "S:spList"); system(cmd)`

Comment: Dear nrussell, thank you for the prompt answer. I'm working in windows 7. Your solution is somehow not working in my computer. Despite I didn't get any error message, I cannot see the comments by using Winzip (I'm using the Winzip version 20.0 as shareware).

Comment: Yeah you will most likely need some type of UNIX shell emulator like MinGW for that to work on Windows. I'm not sure how to achieve this with R's `zip` command; good question though.

Comment: I sent a request to the R Core Development Team. May I get an answer, I will post it here. Thank you again!